# JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false) me tira error cuando levanto el WAR

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Buenos días, estoy teniendo un inconveniente con la ejecución de mi proyecto ya que quiero imprimir automáticamente un ticket (reporte) el cual si lo hago desde un IDE(eclipse) si funciona perfecto, pero al exportar el WAR y levantarlo desde Tomcat, Glassfish o EAP me larga una excepcion. 
El codigo donde larga la Excepcion es:

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reportes/Turno.jasper"));

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, out);   

        //// Justo Aqui Larga la Excepcion
        JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false);
```

Y la excepcion que larga es:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error printing report.
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:214)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.print(JasperPrintManager.java:242)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.print(JasperPrintManager.java:129)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printReport(JasperPrintManager.java:326)
at municipalidad.impresiones.TurnoImpresion.getImprimeTurno(TurnoImpresion.java:51)
at municipalidad.service.TurnoService.getImpresionTurno(TurnoService.java:26)
at municipalidad.rest.TurnoResource.getImprimeTurnoPost(TurnoResource.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterException: No print service found.
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1359)
    at sun.print.RasterPrinterJob.print(RasterPrinterJob.java:1331)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT
```

Comment: ¿Has usado la depuración para intentar entender qué puede ir mal?  Mira [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tu pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: Si, pero salta justo en esa linea y me da ese error, lo que me confunde es que cuando corro desde eclipse funciona perfecto, no se si se trate de un problema de permisos o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Los servidores también están en tu máquina local? El error dice que no encuentra u servicio de impresión

Comment: Si, están instalados en la misma maquina

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica en la manera que llamas la impresión.
Al llamarla de la forma en que lo haces: `JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false);` con el parámetro `false` le estás indicando que no muestre el dialogo de impresión y tratará de imprimirlo en la impresora por defecto. Quizá no tienes configurada una impresora por defecto.

Esto es lo que te indica el error que te dice al final:

```
Caused by: java.awt.print.PrinterException: No print service found.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el viernes descubri que no tengo una impresora por defecto, pero si aparecen las impresoras listadas, ahora estoy viendo como setear una impresora por defecto

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré la solución, subo el código por si alguien mas tiene un problema similar:

```
JasperReport report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reportes/Turno.jasper"));

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());

        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, out);   

        //// Prueba de impresion
        //JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false);


        ////// LO NUEVO

        PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);

        for (PrintService printService : services) {
            if (printService.getName().equals("NOMBRE DE LA IMPRESORA")){
                pj.setPrintService(printService);
                //JasperPrintManager.printReport(print, false);
            }
        }

        JRPrintServiceExporter exporter;
        PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttributeSet = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LETTER);
        printRequestAttributeSet.add(new Copies(1));

        // these are deprecated
        exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE, pj.getPrintService());
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_SERVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SET, pj.getPrintService().getAttributes());
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttributeSet);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PAGE_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.FALSE);
        exporter.exportReport();
```